# libgdx's gradlew doesn't work in Fedora

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, fedora, gradlew

So I tried to create a libgdx project with libgdx-setup:

```
./gradlew desktop:run
```

And I got the following output:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':core:compile'.
```

> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.281 secs
```

It is really strange as I have never met this trouble before. I searched through the internet and I got nothing useful, so I come here to ask for help. Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if something messed up your gradle environment.
Remove your `~/.gradle/` directory or invalidate the caches of gradle. That should do the trick.

Comment: This happens when I am using gdx-setup.jar to create a gdx project and I don't know how to redownload dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried calling it with `--refresh-dependencies` ?